# How to install Ubuntu from a USB key using syslinux?

Tags: installation, bootloader

I'm making a bootable USB key for myself, and one function of it is to install Ubuntu.

I have downloaded the ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso file.

There is a pretty good method for [installation of Red Hat from a USB drive](http://www.softpanorama.org/Commercial_linuxes/RHEL/Installation/installation_from_usb_drive.shtml), but the problem is, when it comes to Ubuntu, what the syslinux.cfg file should be?

I used `syslinux -d /boot/syslinux /dev/sdb1` and put vmlinuz and initrd.img inside it.

Is the following item of syslinux.cfg correct?

```
LABEL InstallUbuntu
MENU LABEL Ubuntu 11.10 Install
KERNEL /boot/syslinux/vmlinuz
APPEND linux load_ramdisk=1 initrd=/boot/syslinux/initrd.img method=hd:sdb1:/
```

Comment: Can you expand your question as to why you are not following the recommended installation method in step 2 http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download

Comment: @fossfreedom Because I want my usb key can also boot with other linux distributions, such as Parted Magic, Lucid Puppy.

Comment: actually i had grub installed on my Kingston USB key , syslinux is kinda obsolete on my side

Comment: @warl0ck It's true, grub is much easier, maybe I should try it next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem using

```
LABEL InstallUbuntu
MENU LABEL Ubuntu 11.10 Install
LINUX /vmlinuz
INITRD /initrd.lz
APPEND boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso
```

Here is the [source](http://www.syslinux.org/archives/2011-January/015991.html) for the information that helped me.